# Unable to fetch for public folder locales in tests for React + i18next

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, i18next

I've got a project which uses `React`, `i18next` for internationalization and `jest` for testing.

### The issue

Whenever I try to run my tests, it seems the `Backend` plugin is doing some fetches to load the translations from the `public/locales` folder, which ends up in an ugly error in the console, which (the main part) says:

`Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 at Object.dispatchError`

Furthermore, **anywhere where I want to use any of the i18n functionalities tests fail**. For example, `i18n.exists(message)` always returns `false` when running in tests.

My guess is that `Backend` is actually making a fetch call to `public` folder, and it fails because during tests the server is not listening and does not return anything from the `public` folder, so basically no translations are loaded.

The project configuration

```
// i18n.js

import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    debug: false,
    defaultNS: 'common',
    fallbackLng: ['es'],
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    },
    ns: ['common', 'comments'],
    react: {
      useSuspense: false,
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

```
// setupTests.js

import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-i18next'),
  useTranslation: () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-i18next').useTranslation(),
    t: (key: string, interpolation: any) =>
      `T_${key}${
        interpolation
          ? `--${Object.keys(interpolation)
              ?.map((k) => `${k}:${interpolation[k]}`)
              .join('--')}`
          : ''
      }`,
  }),
}));
```

And the **locales folder** structure:

[image: location of the locales folder inside the project]

### What I've tried

I've tried to remove the `Backend` plugin from the `use` clauses, and then this error disappears. However, translations do not load anymore in the live app, and the other i18n functionalities keep failing in the tests.

Also, I've tried to load manually the `resources` option, importing directly the `json` file as a resource, and then it seems to work both: errors disappear and `i18n.exists` works as expected. But I don't want to have to load all the `json` files for each namespace manually, since multiple languages are expected to be supported.

### The question

How can I get `Backend` to be able to load the information from the `public/locales` folder, exactly the same as it does in the live app, so that i18n functionalities are working as expected?

Maybe should I mock the calls to `public/locales` folder? If so, how can I do so for all tests (I'm using `fetch-mock-jest` to mock fetch calls).

Thanks!

Comment: https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this tells you how to mock the utilities of `i18n` which I'm already doing in my `setupTests` files as you can see, but it does not tell you how to avoid `i18n` Backend fetching for translations during tests, or how to load those translations files to make `i18n` functionalities to work as they work in the real app. The only thing I can see is creating a `i18n` file for testing, but then I've got to load all namespaces and files as resources, which I cannot because they're in the `public` folder and relative imports are only supported in `src` folder.

Comment: for tests you can also set lng to 'cimode', this will always show the keys

Comment: But this does not solve the problem. I have functionalities to return the translation if it exists, otherwise show a generic message. If I don't have translations loaded, the test won't work because it will never exist and I won't be able to test the other path. That's why I need to load translations, just as the real app does. In fact, you can see that I have already mocked `t` method, so it returns `T_key`. My issue is with the other `i18n` functionalities, such as `exists`.

Comment: The question is, do you want to test your app or do you want to test i18next?

Comment: I want to test my app using i18n. I cannot setup a component and put a big "if you are in testing, don't do what you're supposed to do and call this other method instead". The component is supposed to render a string, and the content of this string depends on a key received by the backend. If the key exists, render the text. Otherwise, render a generic text. I need to load translations to be able to use the existing keys, and be able to simulate the app behaviour as closer as I can to the real behaviour.

Comment: then you also need to make sure the translations can be fetched

Comment: That's what the title and the description of my problem asks for.

Comment: https://github.com/jefflau/jest-fetch-mock